# Select SQL item with date within current week

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

We have a database of films, and need to select the film with a start and end date within the current week. We have two columns in the SQL table, both of type "date", and are written in the format 2015-01-25 (ISO)(YYYY-MM-DD). We need to select the entry that occurs within the current week. The start date for the film is usually the Friday of the week, and the end date is usually the Sunday of the week. I want to be able to show what the upcoming film for the upcoming weekend will be, no matter what day of the week they check. I have written the following PHP and SQL query, but I'm not getting any data back when I echo the $result.

```
$date = strtotime("now");
$last = strtotime('next Sunday');
$date = date('Y-m-d',$date);
$last = date('Y-m-d',$last);

$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM campusFilms WHERE startDate BETWEEN $date AND $last"));
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, and I am happy to elaborate on anything needed. I have searched other StackOverflow questions but none of them quite answered this specific case.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: The *set* of *results* that you *desire*

Comment: @Strawberry Desired result would be, for example, if today's date was 2015-02-05, Big+Hero, id 62 would be returned, along with all the information in that row. I want to pull the entry that has a startDate within the dates that make up the current week. See the SQL Fiddle for the specific id I am talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use [**YEARWEEK()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) ?

```
SELECT whatever_you_need 
FROM campusFilms 
WHERE YEARWEEK(CURDATE()) BETWEEN YEARWEEK(startDate) AND YEARWEEK(endDate);
```

yearweek returns the year and week of any given date which will handle multiple years.

Comment: This looks promising but how would I go about testing the condition of year changes?

Comment: @Michael just make up dates for the curdate() that are in different years... I already tested it, but you can too.. Yearweek will return the year amd week so it wont returm data from a different year and same week

Comment: After further testing and research (As well as application of the YEARWEEK() method in production), I have determined that YEARWEEK() will not work, at least in this form. It is continually returning the previous week's item. But this is totally the right frame of mind. Upon further reading, I found the WEEKOFYEAR(), which is exactly what I need. It will also ignore year which is perfect. Thanks so much for your help John, you have been invaluable.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM campusFilms 
 WHERE WEEK('2015-02-05') BETWEEN WEEK(startDate) AND WEEK(endDate);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/476d3/3

This solution cannot use an index so, if performance is an issue, we can look at alternative solutions.

Comment: This was great! I just replaced the '2015-02-05' with NOW() and it works as expected! Thank you so much! I love the Stack Overflow community!

Comment: Note that this doesn't properly account for years - but mysql has date formatting functions that can help with that

Comment: Does that mean that by this time next year the query will break?

Comment: Yes! Lucky it's still January, eh?

Comment: Is there any way to just ignore the year then?

Comment: I think you should consider providing a more representative data set and corresponding result set - one that includes dates/weeks that overlap the end of year.

Comment: This is exactly what typical data sets will look like. The database is usually only populated with data 1 -2 months out. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Still, "one to months out" could still cover the period from December to January, right? That's the part of the puzzle you might want to focus on!

Comment: Why not just use YEARWEEK? wouldn't that solve multi year issues?

Answer (score 1):

If all you care is to find records where `startdate` is between the Friday and Sunday of the current week, then you don't even need to use PHP to compute dates, you can get mysql to do all the work for you:

```
SELECT *
  FROM campusFilms
 WHERE startDate BETWEEN
       DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL(-2 + MOD(8-DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()),7)) DAY)
       AND
       DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL(MOD(8-DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()),7)) DAY)
```

This works regardless of what day of the week it is today.  If it's Friday, it'll give you films between today and the day after tomorrow.  For Saturdays, it'll give you films between yesterday and tomorrow and for Sundays, it'll give you films between two days ago and today.

Comment: Thanks Aleks G! Your code makes sense, but I get this error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Comment: @Michael Start by testing the query in SQL prompt - there's something wrong with the sql statement

Comment: Ran it at a prompt and still failed. Thanks for your help though! The answer above worked.

Comment: _Still failed_ is as unhelpful as it gets.  What's the error message?